# Unable to launch WAS V4 Admin Server

Tags: server, websphere, admin

I was installing WAS V4 in an window server, during the installation, the system prompt me as the installation cant detect DB2 in my local system while I already make sure the DB2 is running fine in local. I did follow some on line guide which to skip the DB2 detection during the installation and i did finisehed the installation. But the IBM Admin Server v4 services cannot start. Any advice?

Comment: IBM [ended support](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/websphere/support/lifecycle/) for WebSphere Application Server 4 more than 11 years ago.  I very strongly recommend using a newer version of the product, perhaps even [Liberty edition](http://wasdev.net).

Comment: Thanks for the information, but I hope to restore a server similar to our company's old project which was using WAS4. Can I just install a newer version and put the old project in it?

Comment: I have no idea, and I suspect no one here will remember details on such an old product.  Your best option might be to contact IBM; they might be willing to provide support, or they might be able to assist you in migrating to a newer version.

Comment: You should be able to deploy an application developed for an older version of Java and JavaEE and deploy it to a WAS version supporting newer versions, but to what extent that is possible also depends very much on the application and the libraries used there within. I do agree strongly with the other opinions that you should try to deploy this to a newer version anyway. If nothing else, DB2 is not a required component for WAS itself any longer and I believe IBM removed this dependency starting from WAS version 5.0.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, I will try to deploy it to a newer version as my last ressolve , does anyone know if the OS version affecting the WAS? I am installing it in Windows Server 2012 R2, will it be a problems because I still cant determine the complete prerequisite system requirement for WAS4.